# Does a production DJango server fork?

Tags: django

I have been storing some information in global vars in my DJango views.  This information can be accessed by every thread in the Python Django process.  However, I am wondering about how Django behaves in production.  Does a production Django process fork() multiple times to handle requests?  If so this data would not be the same across processes.  Does anyone know if Django forks?

Comment: You shouldn't use global vars - otherwise the problems you mention will occur (of course also depending on the production server you use). Find a more suitable place for your data, probably `request.session`...

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure that it depends on your deployment, but if you are running it under FastCGI or WSGI, then yes, it generally pre-forks a number of server processes to handle incoming requests.

I don't know about running under mod_python, but I think that is being discouraged these days in favour of WSGI.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in this field so I'm answering based only on the grep-ing I've just done.

The **fastcgi** server seems to be able to fork, depending on configuration settings:

http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.2.3/django/core/servers/fastcgi.py#L171
http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.2.3/django/utils/daemonize.py

As for WSGI, I believe that Django side-handling is going straight to the request processing:

http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.2.3/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py#L217

and forking is configured in mod_wsgi: http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/ - embedded mode vs daemon mode - and/or in Apache (worker vs prefork builds).

Answer (score 0):

For mod_wsgi, read:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ProcessesAndThreading

It explains the various models and guidelines in respect to use of common data across threads/processes. Situation isn't much different for other hosting systems.